# how to make li items overflow hidden instead of dropping into next line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make images in one line using li tags, they are going into next line when they exceed the width of div or ul, I want them in line and hide when they exceed.

```css
#thumbsUp{    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: gray;    
    overflow: hidden;
}

#ulThumbs{    
margin: 5px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: red;   
padding-left: 0px;
}

#ulThumbs li{
    margin-left: 5px;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='main'>
        <div id='thumbsUp'>
            <ul id='ulThumbs'>
                <li>a</li>
                <li>b</li>
                <li>c</li>
                <li>d</li>
                <li>e</li>
                <li>f</li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be a way to do this:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  }

ul.thumbs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
ul.thumbs li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="thumbs">
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The li's are `display: inline-block;` and the ul has `white-space: nowrap;` so the li's can't wrap.

Comment: how to add horizental scroll on it

Comment: add overflow-x: scroll; to #ulThumbs{  ... }

Comment: add `overflow-x: auto;` to .container

Comment: Thank you very much Andy

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/kirandash/kcstc868/

```
#thumbsUp{    
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: gray;    
}

#ulThumbs{    
margin: 5px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: red;   
padding-left: 0px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow-x: scroll;
}

#ulThumbs li{
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you please make clear what you need. As per your question, they are in inline now and overflowing items are hidden

Answer (score 0):

Try It Once Don't Use Margins For This Type Of Lay Outs .

```css
#main{
overflow:hidden;
}
#thumbsUp{    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: gray;    
    overflow: hidden;
}

#ulThumbs{    
padding: 5px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: red;   
padding-left: 0px;
}

#ulThumbs li{
    margin-left:0.66%;
    float: left;
    width: 16%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='main'>
        <div id='thumbsUp'>
            <ul id='ulThumbs'>
                <li>a</li>
                <li>b</li>
                <li>c</li>
                <li>d</li>
                <li>e</li>
                <li>f</li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```